# overlapping paragraphs with position:absolute inside relative box

Tags: html, css

Once I tried child box to be inside parent box, paragraphs on child box does not
work to be separated. In this case, how could I separate each paragraphs?

```css
.main_image {
 position: relative;
 height:300px;
 margin:10px;
 top:1%;
}

.main_image img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}


     .main_image p{
     position: absolute;
     top:50px;
     right:30%;
     font-size:3em;
     font-family:PermanentMarker;
     color:#FFFFFF;
    }

    .space {
     top:80px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main_image">
   <img src="images/seoulkoreaart.jpg">
   <p>Korean Seoul</p>
   <p class="space">Art Gallery</p>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put the paragraphs inside an absolutely positioned div, and keep the paragraphs as static/relative?

Comment: Please provide a clearer description of what you are trying to achieve, or better yet, an image of result you want, showing boxes for each div and what you want the paragraph text to do.

Comment: Because you give both p `position:absolute` and given same left and top position.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main_image {
 position: relative;
 height:300px;
 margin:10px;
 top:1%;
}

.main_image img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}


     .main_image .desc{
     position: absolute;
     top:50px;
     right:30%;
     font-size:3em;
     font-family:PermanentMarker;
     color:#000;
    }

    .space {
     top:80px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main_image">
   <img src="images/seoulkoreaart.jpg">
<div class="desc">
   <p>Korean Seoul</p>
   <p class="space">Art Gallery</p>
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `<p>` tags in a `<div>` and assign that div as `position: absolute`:

HTML:

```
<div class="main_image">
      <img src="images/seoulkoreaart.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
          <p>Korean Seoul</p>
          <p class="space">Art Gallery</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_image .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        top:50px;
        right:30%;
        font-size:3em;
        font-family:PermanentMarker;
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qz4vk1su/